# Parsing simple string with awk or sed in linux

Tags: parsing, awk, sed

original string :
`A/trunk/apple/B/trunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange/citrus/Q/trunk/melon/juice/venti/straw/`

Depth of directories will vary, but /trunk part will always remain the same.
And a single character in front of /trunk is the indicator of that line.

desired output :

```
A /trunk/apple
B /trunk/apple
Z /trunk/orange
Q /trunk/melon/juice/venti/straw
```

*** edit
I'm sorry I made a mistake by adding a slash at the end of each path  in the original string which made the output confusing. Original string didn't have the slash in front of the capital letter, but I'll leave it be.

my attempt :

`echo $str1 | sed 's/\(.\/trunk\)/\n\1/g'`

I feel like it should work but it doesn't.

Comment: Your problem is under-specified. Please clearly explain how you define the first and second fields of your desired output. Is it based on letter case? On number of slashes? Other? Note that the solution you show does not do what you ask for: it does not remove the trailing slashes of the 2 first output lines and it adds an empty first output line. Please either fix it, or explain that it is not exactly what you want or change your desired output example. Please do this by editing your question, not in comments.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet edited the question

Comment: @Lunartist The output of the third string should be `Z /trunk/orange/citrus` right?

Comment: @Lunartist, your initial question was having a  good attempted code in it. In editing it was gone so I have readded it, having efforts(tried code) makes a question good one and saves from a question from getting closed. So keep sharing and keep learning on this great forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deal with complex samples input, like where there could be N number of `/` and values after trunk in a single line please try following.

```
awk '
{
  gsub(/[^/]*\/trunk/,OFS"&")
  sub(/^ /,"")
  sub(/\//,OFS"&")
  gsub(/ +[^/]*\/trunk\/[^[:space:]]+/,"\n&")
  sub(/\n/,OFS)
  gsub(/\n /,ORS)
  gsub(/\/trunk/,OFS"&")
  sub(/[[:space:]]+/,OFS)
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                            ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  gsub(/[^/]*\/trunk/,OFS"&")                    ##Globally substituting everything from / to till next / followed by trunk/ with space and matched value.
  sub(/^ /,"")                                   ##Substituting starting space with NULL here.
  sub(/\//,OFS"&")                               ##Substituting first / with space / here.
  gsub(/ +[^/]*\/trunk\/[^[:space:]]+/,"\n&")    ##Globally substituting spaces followed by everything till / trunk till space comes with new line and matched values.
  sub(/\n/,OFS)                                  ##Substituting new line with space.
  gsub(/\n /,ORS)                                ##Globally substituting new line space with ORS.
  gsub(/\/trunk/,OFS"&")                         ##Globally substituting /trunk with OFS and matched value.
  sub(/[[:space:]]+/,OFS)                        ##Substituting spaces with OFS here.
}
1                                                ##Printing edited/non-edited line here.
'  Input_file                                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '{gsub(/\/trunk/,OFS "&");gsub(/trunk\/[^/]*\//,"&\n")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: what if I can have more depth after orange? some could be /trunk/pine/queen/razor/

Comment: @Lunartist, you mean to say `A/trunk/apple/B/trunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange` could be: `A/trunk/apple/B/trunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange/C/apple/banana`? like this? OR `A/trunk/apple/B/trunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange/banana/apple` like this?

Comment: the later one. I achieved what I desired with clumsy double sed, but I want learn from you with your method.

Comment: @Lunartist, so you mean text is `A/trunk/apple/B/trunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange/banana/apple` you are trying but how will we recognize till when we need to look for character putting into new line?

Comment: @Lunartist, Please try my newly added 1st solution and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @Lunartist if you want a solution that works for more than just 1 word after each /trunk/, then include such cases in your sample input/output as right now you're getting a lot of people helping you do what you asked for in the example in your question but by [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002557/parsing-simple-string-with-awk-or-sed-in-linux/70003375?noredirect=1#comment123745165_70002590) what you asked for may not be what you really want.

Comment: you're right fixed the question

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='([^/]+/){2}[^/\n]+' 'RT{sub("/",OFS,RT); print RT}' file
A trunk/apple
B trunk/apple
Z trunk/orange
```

I'm setting `RS` to a regexp describing each string you want to match, i.e. 2 repetitions of non-`/`s followed by `/` and then a final string of non-`/`s (and non-newline for the last string on the input line). `RT` is automatically set to each of the matching strings, so then I just change the first `/` to a blank and print the result.

If each path isn't always 3 levels deep but does always start with `something/trunk/`, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
A/trunk/apple/banana/B/trunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange
```

then:

```
$ awk -v RS='[^/]+/trunk/' 'RT{if (NR>1) print pfx $0; pfx=gensub("/"," ",1,RT)} END{printf "%s%s", pfx, $0}' file
A trunk/apple/banana/
B trunk/apple/
Z trunk/orange
```

Answer (score 2):

In `awk` you can try this solution. It deals with the special requirement of removing forward slashes when the next character is upper case. Will not win a design award but works.

```
$ echo "A/trunk/apple/B/trunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange" | 
    awk -F '' '{ x=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
      if($(i+1)~/[A-Z]/&&$i=="/"){$i=""}; 
      if($i~/[A-Z]/){ printf x""$i" "}
      else{ x="\n"; printf $i } }; print "" }'
A /trunk/apple
B /trunk/apple
Z /trunk/orange
```

Also works for n words. Actually works with anything that follows the given pattern.

```
$ echo "A/fruits/apple/mango/B/anything/apple/pear/banana/Z/ball/orange/anything" | 
    awk -F '' '{ x=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
      if($(i+1)~/[A-Z]/&&$i=="/"){$i=""};
      if($i~/[A-Z]/){ printf x""$i" "}
      else{ x="\n"; printf $i } }; print "" }'
A /fruits/apple/mango
B /anything/apple/pear/banana
Z /ball/orange/anything
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^/]*/& /;s/\//\n/3;P;D' file
```

Separate the first word from the first `/` by a space.

Replace the third `/` by a newline.

Print/delete the first line and repeat.

---

If the first word has the property that it is only one character long:

```
sed 's/./& /;s#/\(./\)#\n\1#;P;D' file
```

Or if the first word has the property that it begins with an upper case character:

```
sed 's/[[:upper:]][^/]*/& /;s#/\([[:upper:][^/]*/\)#\n\1#;P;D' file
```

Or if the first word has the property that it is followed by `/trunk/`:

```
sed -E 's#([^/]*)(/trunk/)#\n\1 \2#g;s/.//' file
```

Comment: Is there a neat solution like this for n words?

Comment: @AndreWildberg I guess you can change the `3` to `n+1` for `n` words? Perhaps another example might clarify what you want?

Comment: E.g. `A/trunk/apple/orange/mange/B/trunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange`

Comment: @AndreWildberg by `n` words I take it you mean a *variable* number of words, in which case you must define the property of the first word. See edit.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm not the OP, I was just curious.

Answer (score 2):

Using `gnu awk` you could use FPAT to set contents of each field using a pattern.

When looping the fields, replace the first `/` with  `/`

```
str1="A/trunk/apple/B/trunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange"

echo $str1 | awk -v FPAT='[^/]+/trunk/[^/]+' '{    
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    sub("/", " /", $i)
    print $i
    }
}'
```

The pattern matches

- `[^/]+` Match any char except `/`
- `/trunk/[^/]+` Match `/trunk/` and any char except `/`

Output

```
A  /trunk/apple
B  /trunk/apple
Z  /trunk/orange
```

---

Other patterns that can be used by FPAT after the updated question:

Matching a word boundary `\\<` and an uppercase char A-Z and after `/trunk` repeat `/` and lowercase chars

```
FPAT='\\<[A-Z]/trunk(/[a-z]+)*'
```

If the length of the strings for the directories after `/trunk` are at least 2 characters:

```
FPAT='\\<[A-Z]/trunk(/[^/]{2,})*'
```

If there can be no separate folders that consist of a single uppercase char A-Z

```
FPAT='\\<[A-Z]/trunk(/([^/A-Z][^/]*|[^/]{2,}))*'
```

Output

```
A /trunk/apple
B /trunk/apple
Z /trunk/orange/citrus
Q /trunk/melon/juice/venti/straw
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
$ str="A/trunk/apple/B/trunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange/citrus/Q/trunk/melon/juice/venti/straw/"
$ sed -E 's|/?(.)(/trunk/)|\n\1 \2|g;s|/$||' <<< "$str"

A /trunk/apple
B /trunk/apple
Z /trunk/orange/citrus
Q /trunk/melon/juice/venti/straw
```

Note the first empty output line. If it is undesirable we can separate the processing of the first output line:

```
$ sed -E 's|(.)|\1 |;s|/(.)(/trunk/)|\n\1 \2|g;s|/$||' <<< "$str"
A /trunk/apple
B /trunk/apple
Z /trunk/orange/citrus
Q /trunk/melon/juice/venti/straw
```

Comment: very clear and straight forward thank you.

Comment: `'s|(.)|\1 |`  is shorter as: `s/./& /`.  Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Update

With your new data file:

```
$ cat file
A/trunk/apple/B/trunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange/citrus/Q/trunk/melon/juice/venti/straw/
```

This GNU `awk` solution:

```
awk '
{
sub(/[/]$/,"")
gsub(/[[:upper:]]{1}/,"& ")
print gensub(/([/])([[:upper:]])/,"\n\\2","g")
}' file
A /trunk/apple
B /trunk/apple
Z /trunk/orange/citrus
Q /trunk/melon/juice/venti/straw
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data will always be in the format provided as a single string, you can try this `sed`.

```
$ sed 's/$/\//;s|\([A-Z]\)\([a-z/]*\)/\([a-z]*\?\)|\1 \2\3\n|g' input_file
```

```
$ echo "A/trunk/apple/pine/skunk/B/trunk/runk/bunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange/T/fruits/apple/mango/P/anything/apple/pear/banana/L/ball/orange/anything/S/fruits/apple/mango/B/rupert/cream/travel/scout/H/tall/mountains/pottery/barnes" | sed 's/$/\//;s|\([A-Z]\)\([a-z/]*\)/\([a-z]*\?\)|\1 \2\3\n|g'
A /trunk/apple/pine/skunk
B /trunk/runk/bunk/apple
Z /trunk/orange
T /fruits/apple/mango
P /anything/apple/pear/banana
L /ball/orange/anything
S /fruits/apple/mango
B /rupert/cream/travel/scout
H /tall/mountains/pottery/barnes
```

Comment: Could you explain why the second line used `|` as the delimeter instead of `/`?

Comment: @Lunartist That would be because the data itself contains a slash `/` which will conflict with `seds` default delimiter thus throwing an error. The first sed command only concentrates on replacing the end of the string bypassing the conflict as there is no slash there.

Answer (score 1):

Some fun with perl, where you can using nonconsuming regex to autosplit into the `@F` array, then just print however you want.

`perl -lanF'/(?=.{1,2}trunk)/' -e 'print "$F[2*$_] $F[2*$_+1]" for 0..$#F/2'`

Step #1:  Split

- `perl -lanF/(?=.{1,2}trunk)/'`
- This will take the input stream, and split each line whenever the pattern `.{1,2}trunk` is encountered
- Because we want to retain `trunk` and the preceeding 1 or 2 chars, we wrap the split pattern in the `(?=)` for a non-consuming forward lookahead
- This splits things up this way:

```
$ echo A/trunk/apple/B/trunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange/citrus/Q/trunk/melon/juice/venti/straw/ | perl -lanF'/(?=.{1,2}trunk)/' -e 'print join " ", @F'
A /trunk/apple/ B /trunk/apple/ Z /trunk/orange/citrus/ Q /trunk/melon/juice/venti/straw/
```

Step 2:  Format output:

- The `@F` array contains pairs that we want to print in order, so we'll iterate half of the array indices, and print 2 at a time:
- `print "$F[2*$_] $F[2*$_+1]" for 0..$#F/2`  --> Double the iterator, and print pairs
- using `perl -l` means each `print` has an implicit `\n` at the end
- The results:

```
$ echo A/trunk/apple/B/trunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange/citrus/Q/trunk/melon/juice/venti/straw/ | perl -lanF'/(?=.{1,2}trunk)/' -e 'print "$F[2*$_] $F[2*$_+1]" for 0..$#F/2'
A /trunk/apple/
B /trunk/apple/
Z /trunk/orange/citrus/
Q /trunk/melon/juice/venti/straw/
```

Endnote:  Perl obfuscation that didn't work.

- Any array in perl can be cast as a hash, of the format (key,val,key,val....)
- So `%F=@F; print "$_ $F{$_}" for keys %F` seems like it would be really slick
- But you lose order:

```
$ echo A/trunk/apple/B/trunk/apple/Z/trunk/orange/citrus/Q/trunk/melon/juice/venti/straw/ | perl -lanF'/(?=.{1,2}trunk)/' -e '%F=@F; print "$_ $F{$_}" for keys %F'
Z /trunk/orange/citrus/
A /trunk/apple/
Q /trunk/melon/juice/venti/straw/
B /trunk/apple/
```